# Linux SSH abnormal activity

Tags: linux, ssh

I found an IP 192.168.1.100 accessed to localhost with public key successfully for 38204 times within two weeks. I checked secure file for more detail about this IP. This client logged in for every second, and sometimes it logged in for every 5 minutes. However, it logged out immediately after logged in. Also the source port number is enumerating. I am not sure if this is an attack?!

[image]

Comment: If it is an attack, probably not very hard (in case of a "professional" attack a rootkit had been installed, and then the traces of the attacks had been removed, thus you didn't see a single ssh login in the logs, and especially no 38204).

Comment: How can this be an attack? It is all on your network, with your computers, and your ssh keys. I suspect this is something you set up yourself and forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

Your server seems to be called "localhost", which makes the logs a little confusing at first glance. It's also not clear whether your server has IP address 192.168.1.100 or something else. However...

The log files show something logging in to your server "localhost" from the server 192.168.1.100 as root. I would suggest that it's not an attack but rather an automated process running something with a command like this, `ssh root@{your_server} /some/command...`.

There are a couple of ways of stopping this login continuing further:

1. They are using a public key so removing the corresponding entry from the file `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` will prevent the login. (Remove the entire file, if necessary.)
2. Adding an `iptables` rule to block inbound `ssh` connections from that server will work. Try `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --src 192.168.1.100 --dport 22 -j REJECT`. (Repeat the command changing `-I` for `-D` to delete the rule.)